# Printing a line at a specified offset in a file

Tags: shell, files, read

I have a file with 50 characters on each line and 50 lines. Each line of the file contains arbitrary letters. I want to specify a character sequence number (ex: 52) and have the appropriate line of letters printed out with a `*` printed in front of the given character.

Comment: Try to be more specific... Is there a language you are trying to do this in? How is the file formatted?

Comment: When you say character number example 52, do you mean ASCII character 52 decimal, the character "R"?  Or do you mean the String "52"? If the character occurs more than once on a line, you want to flag each occurrence, or just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding your specifications, one way would be to compute line and
column numbers from the offset (ignoring newlines), and use those
values to select the proper line and highlight the proper column.

With an input file `in` that it 50 lines like this:

```
00ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
01ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
02ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
03ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
04ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

Then the following script should do approximately what you asked:

```
while read -p '> ' n; do
    n=$((n - 1))
    line=$((n / 50 + 1))
    col=$((n % 50))
    <in sed -n -e "${line}p" | sed "s/^.\{${col}\}/&*/g"
done
```

Example interaction:

```
> 1
*00ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
> 2
0*0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
> 49
00ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrst*uv
> 50
00ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstu*v
> 52
0*1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
> 125
02ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV*WXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

The first call to sed selects the proper line, the second one inserts
a `*` at the proper column.

Answer (score 0):

```
linemod50(){
        dd bs=51 skip="$(($1/50))" count=1 | {
            dd bs=1 count="$(($1%50-!!($1%50)))"
            IFS= read -r rem
            printf "*%s\n" "$rem"
        }   2 >/dev/null
    }
    i=      forty9=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
    while   [ "$((i+=1))" -le 50 ]
    do      echo "$((i%10))$forty9"
    done    >file
    linemod50 478 <file
```

---

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
51 bytes (51 B) copied, 9.5153e-05 s, 536 kB/s
0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
```

It is probably the most efficient solution because `dd` will just seek through directly to your offset. It doesn't work with wide-characters, though, and may produce unexpected results w/ piped input.

It is an excellent solution with seekable input in the C locale.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU or FreeBSD `sed` (for the `-r` extended regular expression option):

This script wraps around to the beginning for both the lines and the character positions.  if you don't want it to do that, comment out or delete the `while` line.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

for O in "$@" ; do
   while [[ "$O" -gt 50 ]] ; do O=$(( $O -50 )) ; done
   O1=$(( $O - 1 ))
   sed -r -n "$O s/^(.{$O1})(.*)/\1\*\2/ p" input.txt
done


$ for i in {1..50} ; do printf "%02i%s\n" "$i" "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv" ; done > input.txt

$ ./offset.sh 3 10 52 100
03*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
10ABCDEFG*HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
0*2ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
50ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstu*v
```